# Where can I find a Windows VM image?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine

I am running Windows XP Home and would like to run a virtual machine of XP, Server 2003, or Windows 7. Where can I find a VM image to download? The only XP image I've found only works on Windows 7.

Comment: You almost certainly cannot find that.  Anyone distributing such an image other then Microsoft almost certainly would be violating MS license.  You may want to consider picking up a [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/default.aspx) subscription which gives you access to licenses media for testing and learning how things work.  With that you can create your VMs

Answer (score 5):

Here is a link:  http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en

Microsoft provides these Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image's that run for six months before expiring but they also do not allow for activating or registering. From Microsoft:

> Brief Description
>   VPC Hard Disk Images for testing websites with different Internet Explorer versions on Windows XP and Windows Vista

Granted these images only work with Microsoft products.  If you search Microsoft.com as well there are developer prievew VHD's available for trial for other products

Comment: +1 on the IE images. Otherwise the comment about TechNet is spot on. I've found Microsoft likes to offer discounts on those subscriptions on a regular basis, so look around if you go that route.

Comment: This image seems to enforce activation, and fails to log in without activation immediately after VirtualBox guest additions installation and reboot (network still not fuctional). So this seems to be a dead end. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575 XP section does not even mention the activation, and they claim it will be functional within 4 months, but that's different from the reality.

Comment: @philpirozhkov  I think the images are designed only for Virtual PC 2007 not Virtual Box.  Try it with Virtual PC 2007 and see what happens.  Also on the link you posted - scroll down below the download to **Notes and see what it says about activation.

Answer (score 3):

New link to retrieve Windows VM image : http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

Now, there are differents virtualization platforms (VirtualBox, Virtual PC, VMWare ...)